# What is the structure group of the Hopf fibration $S_1\rightarrow S_3 \stackrel{p}\rightarrow S_2$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

I am studying fiber bundles and have thoroughly reviewed the famous example of the Möbius strip. In that example, I learned how to discover that the structure group of the Möbius strip fiber bundle was $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I am now trying to expand the complexity of the examples I am studying and have turned to the Hopf fibration. Although I have seen a lot of material regarding this famous fiber bundle, I can't find any analysis of the structure group of the Hopf fibration. I know that it is certainly $\operatorname{Diff}(S_1)$, but I suspect that it can be made smaller just as the Möbius strip's structure group can be made smaller than the full diffeomorphism group of its fiber. What is the smallest structure group of the Hopf fibration and how do we know this?

Comment: It is a principal bundle, so you can get from $\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$ down to $S^1$ without effort.

Comment: A connection with holonomy smaller than $S^1$ would be flat. But there is a nonzero Chern class, so no smaller subgroup.

Comment: Isn't the fact that the Hopf fibration is a principal bundle a bit circular relative to my question? Knowing that the Hopf fibration is a principal bundle means that we know the fiber *is* the structure group, but I don't fully understand how we know what the structure group is in this case? Perhaps I am looking for an actual bundle atlas that demonstrates how every transition function is in $S_1$ and not in any smaller group? Maybe the proof I seek is that $S_1$ is the structure group in the first place? Perhaps this question is actually very elementary....

Comment: @BoundaryValue It may be a worthwhile exercise for you to construct a bundle atlas with transition functions in $S^1$. This can be done explicitly by treating $S^3$ as unit quaternions and writing down a faithful action of $U(1)$.

Comment: How are you defining the Hopf fibration? Most texts will define it as a principal fibration using a given action of $S^1$ on $S^3\cong SU(2)$.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you said that the structure group of the Moebius strip can be reduced to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, rather than saying that it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. You want to know not what the structure group of the Hopf fibration is (because that is just given in the definition of the Hopf fibration), but what it can be reduced to. This might help avoid the apparent circularity. Perhaps also give the definition of the Hopf fibration that you want to start with, and we can then see what reductions to carry out.

Answer (score 4):

It is a principal bundle, so you can get from $\operatorname{Diff}(S^1)$
down to $S^1$ without effort. A connection with holonomy smaller than $S^1$ would be flat. But there is a nonzero Chern class, so no smaller subgroup.

Comment: You don't need Chern classes: if you reduce, then the bundle reduces to a surface covering the 2-sphere, so a union of 2-spheres, and could then pick any one of them, and reduce to a trivial bundle. So you only need to know why Hopf isn't trivial, for which you can use the homology.

Comment: Isn't $Diff(S^1)\simeq O(2)$? Then since $S^2$ is simply connected the first Stiefel-Whitney class $\omega_1$ vanishes and there is a reduction of structure to $SO(1)=U(1)=S^1$.

Comment: @Tyrone: yes, as you say. By definition the Hopf fibration is defined as a principal circle bundle, using multiplication by unit length complex numbers, so we don't need to reduce from the diffeomorphism group of the circle, since that is already given to us. Alternatively, we could say that the unit circle in the complex plane acts, giving an orientation to the fibers, so we can reduce to orientation preserving diffeomorphisms without looking at the Steifel-Whitney. But it is good to see an example of Steifel-Whitney classes, so your point of view is comforting.